# What was 250,000 rubles worth in 1918?

Tags: currency, russian-revolution, ukraine

Circa 1918, during the [Ukrainian War of Independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_War_of_Independence) and the Russian Revolution, Nestor Makhno's army expropriated [250,000 rubles](https://books.google.com/books?id=pMji9s9WOlwC&pg=PA41) from a bank, per Skirda 2004.

Is there a way to contextualize the size/importance of that amount in today's terms? My understanding is that, with inflation, there is no direct conversion, but perhaps there is another way to put it in terms of an officer or peasant's annual income and its buying power in the period? Also interested in reliable sources that establish a connection.

Comment: A bank in which national value form wage labour system?  Unless they’re silver the gross regional instability means a comparison is impossible.

Comment: The question is if these were gold or paper rubles. 1 gold ruble contained approximately 0.8 gram of gold, in which case a meaningful calculation is possible. A paper ruble at the time was not supported by anything or any entity, so I do not see a reason to waste time on such calculations. (Not that it was worthless, just its real buying power was highly dependent on the locale.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming gold pricing (why steal paper rubles) combined with long term labour:gold proxies (USD gold values compared USD labour prices):

- 2022USD: 100-140,000 in labour time
- 2022USD: 400,000 in capital goods (factories, governments, etc)
- 2022USD: 6.4 million in free beers*

*This sum calculated by liquidating 400k of capital as if it were to buy free beers based on the beer/capital transformation in the US economy from 1918

You’re looking at a small local business worth of rubles which if liquidated in a one off purchase of household goods could make a shitload of rural workers in the region very happy for a very short period of time. Basically like robbing a very small regional bank; or ripping off 40 automatic teller machines worth of skilled worker outputs.

It isn’t a significant expropriation.

Comment: Did "gold" rubles exist yet in 1918?

Answer (score 0):

The [Australian Reserve Bank has an online inflation calculator](https://www.rba.gov.au/calculator/) that can be used for amounts going back to 1901 CE. The [Bank of England](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/monetary-policy/inflation/inflation-calculator) has a similar calculator that can be used for amounts going back to 1209 CE.  [New Zealand](https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/monetary-policy/inflation-calculator/) has one for amounts to 1862. Even [Iran](https://www.cbi.ir/InflationCalculator/InflationCalculator_en.aspx) has one for amounts going back to 1936.

Websites for Russian inflation only go back to [1991](https://planetcalc.com/250/) or [1992](https://www.in2013dollars.com/russia/inflation/1992?amount=250000).

One thing that could be done is to try to get a comparison for Russia for amounts from 1918 CE is to compare the cost of a group of items back then and now. Items such as: a loaf of bread, a pair of shoes, if possible, a house or dacha for the wealthy, the salary or an office worker or the wages of a factory worker.

Comment: While I agree that comparison for goods is the best way, I think your examples are extremely flowed. E.g even during piece, real estate price for given real estate can shift an order of magnitude,  if you talk about “a dacha” that ads another 1-2 magnitudes of fluctuation, and during war/revolution the price can go down to zero. Salary of office workers, army, during a revolution/war is also not really market based. Realistically, I would compare to something that somehow tied to foreign trade, eg. value in gold.

Comment: 1918 in this area (I’m not even going to name it) was unstable politically nationally economically. The instability means a time series can’t be constructed